# Can you handle both Int and Float while defining a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, function-definition

I'm working on a Haskell problem to try and learn the language. I'm trying to recursively add all of the elements in a list, so:

```
[5,5] -> 10 and [5.0, 5.0] -> 10.0
```

I know how to recursively solve this, but my question is, how do you handle both Ints and Floats when defining a function? Right now I have:

```
add :: [Int] -> Int
```

which doesn't work for float. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use Either. I have ```import Data.Either``` and my function definition is currently ```add :: Either [Int] [Float] -> Either Int Float```.  It works for Int but not Float.

Comment: That's what the `Num` typeclass is for

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to add :: (Num a) => [a] -> a but it still raises an error for Float

Comment: @SamJones - what is the new error message?

Comment: @FrancisKing i'm getting ```<interactive>:1:16: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from the literal ‘7.0’
    • In the expression: 7.0
      In the first argument of ‘add’, namely ‘[7.0, 7.0]’
      In the expression: add [7.0, 7.0] ```. I've changed my function definition to ```add :: Num a => [a] -> a```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you're looking for a typeclass. In this particular case, since you want to add numbers together, you want the [`Num`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) typeclass, which (among other things) provides the addition function

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

So your signature should look like

```
add :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

and the function can be written recursively

```
add [] = 0
add (x:xs) = x + add xs
```

Note that integer literals, such as `0` in this example, are internally treated as `Num a => a`. Effectively, the Haskell compiler will compile the number `0` to `fromInteger (0 :: Integer)`, where `fromInteger` is another function in the `Num` typeclass. Hence, integer literals are polymorphic.

Finally, while there's nothing *wrong* with this implementation, the function you're looking at actually comes built-in to Haskell. It's called [`sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum).

```
sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a => a
```

Note that `Foldable` is a typeclass for, fittingly, things that can be folded over. The list type `[]` is an example of a `Foldable`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @SilvioMayolo it's very in-depth. I'm trying to teach myself recursion which is why I'm not using sum. I've tried out the code you provided and I'm getting an error ```<interactive>:1:16: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from the literal ‘7.0’
    • In the expression: 7.0
      In the first argument of ‘add’, namely ‘[7.0, 7.0]’
      In the expression: add [7.0, 7.0] ``` how would I go about fixing this? Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the type signature for your `add` function? If the signature is `add :: Num a => [a] -> a`, then `add [7.0, 7.0]` should work, since fractional literals have a `Fractional` constraint, which defaults to `Double`.

Comment: It works!! It wasn't working before because of another error I made. Thank you again for the help!!